# Kivy with Python

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

How do I create interaction between widgets on Kivy? I am making a game where if a block hits another block it will start over I made all the blocks but I just cant get how to make interaction attributes! How do I make Kivy know when the two widgets touched and how do I make the game restart after the touch?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the collide_widget method found in every widget you create. its just the same like the pong game tutorial found in the kivy docs